# what is the d3js v4 equivalent of `d3.rebind`?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

curious, what is the d3js v4 equivalent of `d3.rebind` ? https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Internals.md

Comment: I agree, found that just after asking.  feel free to link  and mark this as a dupe :-)

Comment: I already marked. When you see "Possible duplicate of" in SO, that's an automatic comment, I didn't wrote that!

Comment: oh nice,  carry on then.

Comment: Also, it should have informed you that someone marked it as a duplicate and offered you the chance to accept it.

Comment: don't see that feature yet in the Android mobile app 